# android SIM/SD card alert showing up after opening the app

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, sim-card

I'm experiencing an issue with my android app. Whenever I install it from google play and open it, the phone starts complaining that there's no SIM/SD card (obviously the card is there and works fine):

[image]

I have to remove the app and reboot the phone. I wonder if it's software-related issue and if anyone has experienced that.

The list of permissions the app uses:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

it happens on Samsung Galaxy S7 active (7.0)

Comment: I don't think that this issue is related to your app. I think it is the device firmware issue.

Comment: @VladMatvienko The thing is that the issue doesn't happen when I don't launch the app.

Comment: ok, but does a similar issue happen on the other devices?